# Problema al recoger datos de un formulario php. Muy basico

Tags: php, array, formularios

Estoy empezando en php, y tengo que hacer un ejercicio para tratar los datos de un formulario. El ejercicio es simple, pero estoy atascadisimo. Llevo 4 dias mirandolo y buscando, pero no encuentro solucion.

Se trata de una agenda. Tengo 2 input text para meter nombre y numero, y se los tengo que enviar al servidor. Los recojo en dos arrays. Ahora, no consigo empujarlos. He probado array_push, he probado de todo.

Me estoy fijando en un ejercicio parecido de mi profesor, dejo el codigo.

```
<body>
        <?php
            // Se comprueba que se ha enviado un número entre 1 y 49 si no es así la variable $numero toma el valor vacío
            if (isset($_POST['numero'])  && is_numeric($_POST['numero']) && $_POST['numero']>=0 && $_POST['numero']<=49)
                $numero=$_POST['numero'];
            else 
                $numero="";

            // Se crea el array para contener los distintos números que el usurio vaya guardando
            // Los valores se guardan en variables input de tipo hidden, cuyos nombre varían de "a0" a "a5"
            $quiniela=array(); //Creación del array

            // El código va recorriendo las variables hidenn transportadas y se introducen en quiniela
            $salir=false;
            $i=0;
            while (!$salir){
                if (isset($_POST["a".$i])){
                    $quiniela[$i]=$_POST["a".$i];
                    $i++;
                }else
                    $salir=true;
            }

            // comprobamos si el nuevo número que introduce el usuario esta en la lista, si no es así, se incluye
            $estaEnLaLista=false;
            if (count($quiniela)<6 && !empty($numero)){
                for($i=0;$i<count($quiniela) && !$estaEnLaLista; $i++)
                    if ($quiniela[$i]==$numero)
                        $estaEnLaLista=true;
                if (!$estaEnLaLista)
                    $quiniela[]=$numero;
            }
        ?>
        <header><h1>Números Lotería Primitiva</h1></header>
        <section>
            <div id="formulario">
                <!-- formulario que inserta el nuevo valor del usuario -->
                <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="formu">
                    <label for="numero">Número: </label> <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" maxlength="2" size="2" /> <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />

                    <!--
                        Cada vez que actualizamos la página creamos valores de tipo input hidden para transportar los valores escogidos por el usuario 
                    -->
                    <?php
                        for ($i=0; $i<count($quiniela); $i++)                   
                            print "<input type='hidden' name='a".$i."' value='".$quiniela[$i]."' />";
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Presentación de los valores escogidos por el usuario -->
            <div class="escogidos">
                    <?php
                        for ($i=0; $i<count($quiniela); $i++)
                            if ($i==0)
                                print $quiniela[$i];
                            else
                                print ", ".$quiniela[$i];
                    ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Ese es el codigo de mi profesor, y lo que no entiendo, es esta parte.

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<count($quiniela); $i++)                   
    print "<input type='hidden' name='a".$i."' value='".$quiniela[$i]."' />";
?>
```

Me ha explicado 3-4 veces, que es para mandar los datos por hidden, cosa que es obligatoria, pero no lo entiendo, y poniendo echo $nombres, no me muestra nada, por eso se, que el vector esta vacio, y es, porque no llegan al vector.

Estoy perdido, y entiendo perfectamente el codigo, se porque se hace cada cosa, pero me pierdo al enviar los datos hidden a los vectores.

Yo, tengo varios codigos, ya lo he intentado hacer con un solo vector, poniendo nombres en indice y numero en valor, pero tampoco me sale. Esto es lo que hago, y no me sale.

```
<?php 
        $nombres = [];
        $numeros = [];

        if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
            $nombreAux = $_POST['nombre'];
        }else{
            $nombreAux = "";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['numero'])){
            $numeroAux = $_POST['numero'];
        }else{
            $numeroAux = "";
        }

        echo $nombreAux;
        echo $numeroAux;

        $salir=false;
        $i=0;
            while (!$salir){
                if (isset($_POST["nombre".$i])){
                    $nombres[$i]=$_POST["nombre".$i];

                    $i++;
                }else
                    $salir=true;
            }
        $salirNum=false;
        $j=0;
            while (!$salirNum){
                if (isset($_POST["numero".$j])){
                    $numeros[$j]=$_POST["numero".$j];
                    $j++;
                }else
                    $salirNum=true;
            }
```

En el while, entra, pero en el if de nombre, no, y entiendo, que es porque no le llegan datos.
No se si me explico bien, no quiero solucion al codigo, quiero saber como tratar los hidden y mandarlos. La verdad, que php me esta pareciendo lioso, yo, vengo de Java, y llegue hasta un nivel intermedio en java, se manejar perfectamente vectores de Java, arrayList, etc, pero estoy perdido.

Siento por el tocho de hilo que he escrito, y muchisimas gracias por sus respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El código es un poco *mareante* en el sentido de que (me parece) da demasiadas vueltas, marea demasiado los datos para obtener un resultado, manosea demasiado los datos (es lo que se puede apreciar a primera vista). Pero dejemos eso por ahora. Tu problema principal es que en el `POST` buscas un valor bajo la clave `nombre`, pero en el formulario no aparece ningún elemento cuyo `name="nombre"`. Cuando se envía un formulario, se crea un array asociativo cuyas claves son cada etiqueta `name` de los elementos del form, y los valores sus valores...

Comment: ... Algo que puedes hacer para ver lo que estás posteando es esto: `var_dump($POST);`  ... lo que hay en `$_POST` realmente es un array. Ese mismo array se puede trabajar para hacer verificaciones, agregar o quitar cosas, etc. Por eso digo en parte que el código es algo *mareante*, porque parece que crea nuevos arrays sin necesidad. Es sólo una impresión que me atrevo a manifestar sin conocer a fondo el contexto.

Comment: Si, doy muchas vueltas. Empece con php el lunes, y es mi primer programa en este lenguaje. Gracias por la respuesta.